# SFINAE: What is happening here?

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to understand a C++ code, and have come across SFINAE construct (which is new to me). I have created a minimal example, based on the code I am looking at below:

```
#include<iostream>

/* ----------------------------------------------
 Define two kernels: characterized by their dimension
   ---------------------------------------------- */
struct Kern2
{
  static constexpr int dim = 2;
};

struct Kern3
{
  static constexpr int dim = 3;
};

/* ----------------------------------------------
 Choose which function to evaluate based on 
 dimension of Kern (Kern::dim)
   ---------------------------------------------- */
template<class Kern,
         typename std::enable_if<Kern::dim == 2, bool>::type = true>
inline void apply_kern(){
  std::cout << "dim=2" << "\n";
}

template<class Kern,
         typename std::enable_if<Kern::dim == 3, bool>::type = false>
inline void apply_kern(){
  std::cout << "dim=3" << "\n";
}

// Try to see if the above SFINAE construct works!
int main()
{

 apply_kern<Kern2>(); // should print 'dim=2'
 apply_kern<Kern3>(); // should print 'dim=3'

  return 0;
}
```

This gives as output:

```
> dim=2
> dim=3
```

which is exactly what it's supposed to do. However, I am unable to understand exactly *how* this works? In particular, it appears that the same output is created if I switch the

```
typename std::enable_if<Kern::dim == 2, bool>::type = true
```

lines to:

```
typename std::enable_if<Kern::dim == 2, bool>::type = false
```

So I'm wondering what the meaning of these is? If someone could kindly explain what's going on, I'd greatly appreciate it! I haven't been able to find this precise way to use SFINAE online, unfortunately.

Thanks!

Comment: With the mentioned modification, your code shouldn't compile.

Comment: Both `g++` and `clang++` accepts the change (_-std=c++11/14/17_).

Comment: @TedLyngmo: did I miss something? https://godbolt.org/z/wbvn7I

Comment: The `=true` or `=false` is not a comparison, it is just the default value for the template parameter if it is omitted. The SFINAE magic is done inside `std::enable_if`, not in the `=true/false`.

Comment: There is a nice introduction written by Eli Bendersky which I just consulted these days: [SFINAE and enable_if](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/sfinae-and-enable_if/).

Comment: @geza We probably got different versions. If I changed to the version I compiled at home, it compiled at godbolt too :) Edit: Nope, the code wasn't changed here... [my version](https://godbolt.org/z/Lp-JGO)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Your version is not the same as OP's one, so I don't really see why it is relevant.

Comment: I removed the parameters to `main` and removed the `;` after the `main` function to remove warnings about those. I then changed the `enable_if` line to `false`. The test should still be relevant, shouldn't it? ...or did I (inadvertedly) do something to make the questioned change compilable?

Comment: @Sam Why not remove the `int argc, char *argv[]`parameters to `main` and the `;` after `main`?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo: Sure, why not.

Comment: Great! @geza do you see the relevance now?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Can you explain, why it is relevant? I said, that the modified version shouldn't compile. And actually, it doesn't compile (there're godbolt links for the proof). Then you say (if I didn't misunderstand you), that it does compile, and you provide a **different** modification, which compiles. But as it is a different modification, I still don't get, why it is relevant, regarding that OP's modification compiles or not. Your modification semantically equivalent OP's original code (it means, that it's actually a modification which doesn't change the meaning of code)

Comment: It's relevant because it _does_ compile in both c++/clang++ as I claimed. The reason the proof failled had nothing to do with the change in question. It would have failed at godbolt with those settings even with the original code so you did not test the actual change at all with your proof. The current code will let you do just that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: You are wrong. Copy the original code into godbolt. It [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/K6mWu0). Now, apply the change (modify `Kern::dim == 3` to `Kern::dim == 2`. That's the change OP did.). It won't compile. It's as simple as that. As your change is different (and your change doesn't change the meaning of the program at all, as the **default value of the SFINAE value true/false doesn't matter in this program**), it is irrelevant.

Comment: @geza Then one of us misunderstood what the actual change was. I interpreted it as OP changed the top template from `type = true` to `type = false`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: one of us :) It was me. Apologies.

Comment: @geza No worries! Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
typename std::enable_if<Kern::dim == 2, bool>::type = true>
```

That says:

```
typename:
```

the following term defines a type

```
std::enable_if<Kern::dim == 2, bool>
```

This template defines a type of the second template parameter IF the condition in the first parameter is true. So here, if dimm == 2 is true, the template `std::enable_if` provide a type bool which can be accessed with the `::type`.

If the condition was true, the term:

```
typename std::enable_if<Kern::dim == 3, bool>::type
```

becomes simply:

```
bool
```

Now you add `= true` after it. Did you use the bool value anywhere? NO! So it simply doesn't matter at all! you also can write:

```
typename std::enable_if<Kern::dim == 3, int>::type = 42
```

It will result in the same, as you did not use the value you define here!

The condition you check is in `Kern::dim == 3`. This one must be true or false.

If the condition is evaluated to `false`, the template `enable_if` did not contain a `type` and the expression fails. Here SFINAE comes into play. This failure will not be an error but makes the template definition "invisible" as it "can not" be used cause of the failure.

Add-On for the addition question in the comments:

Sure, you can add a name to your bool template default paramter and use it in your code below like this:

```
template<class Kern,
         typename std::enable_if<Kern::dim == 2, bool>::type myVal = true>
inline void apply_kern(){
  std::cout << "dim=2" << "\n";
  std::cout << "bool val: " << myVal << std::endl;
}
```

BTW:
We often see SFINAE used in cases, where a simple template overload works the same way. Often the overload is easier to read ( here maybe not :-) ). I give it only as a hint: Check if SFINAE is really needed and think of a overload instead.

Template overload instead of SFINAE:

```
/* ----------------------------------------------
   Define two kernels: characterized by their dimension
   ---------------------------------------------- */
struct Kern2 { static constexpr int dim = 2; };
struct Kern3 { static constexpr int dim = 3; };

/* ----------------------------------------------
   Choose which function to evaluate based on 
   dimension of Kern (Kern::dim)
   ---------------------------------------------- */
template < int x > inline void apply_kern_impl();

template<>
inline void apply_kern_impl<2>() { std::cout << "dim=2" << "\n"; }

template<>
inline void apply_kern_impl<3>() { std::cout << "dim=3" << "\n"; }

template< typename T>
inline void apply_kern() { apply_kern_impl<T::dim>(); }

int main()
{
    apply_kern<Kern2>(); // should print 'dim=2'
    apply_kern<Kern3>(); // should print 'dim=3'

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great start. Now we need to explain how it works when the condition is false :)

Comment: @Klaus: Thank you for your step-by-step answer. This is very helpful. I'm wondering, why we have to set a default value for bool? Would it be posible to somehow access the bool ::type inside the function?

Comment: @Sam Yes, you would just have to put a name between `::type` and `=`. However, you don't _need_ to use it in the function (it's only there for SFINAE) and the default value means that users don't have to write `apply_kern<Kern2, true>();` (or `false`, it does not matter) but only `apply_kern<Kern2>()`.

Comment: @Klaus: "and the default value means that users don't have to write `apply_kern<Kern2, true>();` (or `false`, it does not matter) but only `apply_kern<Kern2>()`" - Great explanation! Exactly what I needed. Thank you for these details. :)

Comment: @Sam: Your use case is good as example, but in real world code we often see SFINAE used more often as needed. Mostly a simple template overload do the same. I added a example which do the same without SFINAE.

Comment: This is now a fantastic answer all around.

Comment: This answer taught me more about enable_if than I managed to learn after hours of reading books and searching online for explicit examples.

Answer (score 1):

`std::enable_if<bool expression, return type of function>::type` tells the compiler at compile time, compile this if the bool expression is true. So when you call the `apply_kern<Kern2>()` in your `main()` the compiler enters the first `std::enable_if` because you Kern::dim is indeed 2. If for example you did not call `apply_kern<Kern3>()`, the compiler would notice that the second `std::enable_if` was false and the scope inside it was not gonna get compiled. It's like an if statement, but in compile time. You could also use a templated function with 2 template aliases for `Kern2` and `Kern3` respectively and have the same exact result if you find this syntax strange. 
For the same result in the last question i'd try `typename std::enable_if<!(Kern::dim == 2), bool>::type inline void apply_kernel(){...}`.

Comment: @LeoStar: Thank you for your answer! So the point is simply to provide the compile with some expression that will fail, except if we are in the desired case? Is that right? In particular, there is no deeper meaning to the use of the particular construct employed in the code that I'm looking at?

Comment: @Sam Correct. The type and default value chosen there are irrelevant, they remain unused. The entire purpose is to provide _no_ type if the condition is not fulfilled, which leads to substitution failure (and thus ignoring that template). The default value is for convenience of the user (if you remove the default value everything still works, the user would just have to add a meaningless value to the template parameter list when calling `apply_kern`).

Comment: @Sam Actually you need only to write the expression that you want your compiler to compile. In the other cases in compile time the bool expression inside the std::enable_if is gonna return false and this way the function in not gonna get compiled. I would think it like the name of the enable_if: Write all the situations in which you want to get the compiler compile this. It's just a matter or  implementation, but with the right bool expressions inside enable_if. If you add an extra check inside the std::enable_if like f.e. std::is_same, it gains a deeper meaning fir template metaprogramming